# Change the source code of a Method definition

Tags: r, function, methods, r-s4

I would like to temporarily change the source code of a Method definition.
Eg, add a warning message after `if (is.null(y))` in `kernlab::kqr`

I know how to show the souce code of the Method using `getMethod`

```r
library(kernlab)

kernlab::kqr
#> standardGeneric for "kqr" defined from package "kernlab"
#> 
#> function (x, ...) 
#> standardGeneric("kqr")
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000027124698>
#> <environment: 0x00000000270830c0>
#> Methods may be defined for arguments: x
#> Use  showMethods("kqr")  for currently available ones.

getMethod("kqr","matrix")
#> Method Definition:
#> 
#> function (x, ...) 
#> {
#>     .local <- function (x, y, scaled = TRUE, tau = 0.5, C = 0.1, 
#>         kernel = "rbfdot", kpar = "automatic", reduced = FALSE, 
#>         rank = dim(x)[1]/6, fit = TRUE, cross = 0, na.action = na.omit) 
#>     {
#>         if ((tau > 1) || (tau < 0)) 
#>             stop("tau has to be strictly between 0 and 1")
#>         ret <- new("kqr")
#>         param(ret) <- list(C = C, tau = tau)
#>         if (is.null(y)) 
#>             x <- na.action(x)
#>         else {
#>             df <- na.action(data.frame(y, x))
#>             y <- df[, 1]
#>             x <- as.matrix(df[, -1])
#>         }
#>         ncols <- ncol(x)
#>         m <- nrows <- nrow(x)
#>         tmpsc <- NULL
#>         x.scale <- y.scale <- NULL
#>         if (length(scaled) == 1) 
#>             scaled <- rep(scaled, ncol(x))
#>         if (any(scaled)) {
#>             co <- !apply(x[, scaled, drop = FALSE], 2, var)
#>             if (any(co)) {
#>                 scaled <- rep(FALSE, ncol(x))
#>                 warning(paste("Variable(s)", paste("`", colnames(x[, 
#>                   scaled, drop = FALSE])[co], "'", sep = "", 
#>                   collapse = " and "), "constant. Cannot scale data."))
#>             }
#>             else {
#>                 xtmp <- scale(x[, scaled])
#>                 x[, scaled] <- xtmp
#>                 x.scale <- attributes(xtmp)[c("scaled:center", 
#>                   "scaled:scale")]
#>                 y <- scale(y)
#>                 y.scale <- attributes(y)[c("scaled:center", "scaled:scale")]
#>                 y <- as.vector(y)
#>                 tmpsc <- list(scaled = scaled, x.scale = x.scale, 
#>                   y.scale = y.scale)
#>             }
#>         }
#>         if (is.character(kernel)) {
#>             kernel <- match.arg(kernel, c("rbfdot", "polydot", 
#>                 "tanhdot", "vanilladot", "laplacedot", "besseldot", 
#>                 "anovadot", "splinedot"))
#>             if (is.character(kpar)) 
#>                 if ((kernel == "tanhdot" || kernel == "vanilladot" || 
#>                   kernel == "polydot" || kernel == "besseldot" || 
#>                   kernel == "anovadot" || kernel == "splinedot") && 
#>                   kpar == "automatic") {
#>                   cat(" Setting default kernel parameters ", 
#>                     "\n")
#>                   kpar <- list()
#>                 }
#>         }
#>         if (!is.function(kernel)) 
#>             if (!is.list(kpar) && is.character(kpar) && (class(kernel) == 
#>                 "rbfkernel" || class(kernel) == "laplacedot" || 
#>                 kernel == "laplacedot" || kernel == "rbfdot")) {
#>                 kp <- match.arg(kpar, "automatic")
#>                 if (kp == "automatic") 
#>                   kpar <- list(sigma = mean(sigest(x, scaled = FALSE, 
#>                     frac = 1)[c(1, 3)]))
#>                 cat("Using automatic sigma estimation (sigest) for RBF or laplace kernel", 
#>                   "\n")
#>             }
#>         if (!is(kernel, "kernel")) {
#>             if (is(kernel, "function")) 
#>                 kernel <- deparse(substitute(kernel))
#>             kernel <- do.call(kernel, kpar)
#>         }
#>         if (!is(kernel, "kernel")) 
#>             stop("kernel must inherit from class `kernel'")
#>         if (!reduced) 
#>             H = kernelMatrix(kernel, x)
#>         else H = csi(x, kernel = kernel, rank = rank)
#>         c = -y
#>         A = rep(1, m)
#>         b = 0
#>         r = 0
#>         l = matrix(C * (tau - 1), m, 1)
#>         u = matrix(C * tau, m, 1)
#>         qpsol = ipop(c, H, A, b, l, u, r)
#>         alpha(ret) = coef(ret) = primal(qpsol)
#>         b(ret) = dual(qpsol)[1]
#>         xmatrix(ret) <- x
#>         ymatrix(ret) <- y
#>         kernelf(ret) <- kernel
#>         kpar(ret) <- kpar
#>         type(ret) <- ("Quantile Regresion")
#>         if (fit) {
#>             fitted(ret) <- predict(ret, x)
#>             if (!is.null(scaling(ret)$y.scale)) 
#>                 fitted(ret) <- fitted(ret) * tmpsc$y.scale$"scaled:scale" + 
#>                   tmpsc$y.scale$"scaled:center"
#>             error(ret) <- c(pinloss(y, fitted(ret), tau), ramploss(y, 
#>                 fitted(ret), tau))
#>         }
#>         else fitted(ret) <- NULL
#>         if (any(scaled)) 
#>             scaling(ret) <- tmpsc
#>         cross(ret) <- -1
#>         if (cross == 1) 
#>             cat("\n", "cross should be >1 no cross-validation done!", 
#>                 "\n", "\n")
#>         else if (cross > 1) {
#>             pinloss <- 0
#>             ramloss <- 0
#>             crescs <- NULL
#>             suppressWarnings(vgr <- split(sample(1:m, m), 1:cross))
#>             for (i in 1:cross) {
#>                 cind <- unsplit(vgr[-i], factor(rep((1:cross)[-i], 
#>                   unlist(lapply(vgr[-i], length)))))
#>                 cret <- kqr(x[cind, ], y[cind], tau = tau, C = C, 
#>                   scale = FALSE, kernel = kernel, cross = 0, 
#>                   fit = FALSE)
#>                 cres <- predict(cret, x[vgr[[i]], ])
#>                 crescs <- c(crescs, cres)
#>             }
#>             if (!is.null(scaling(ret)$y.scale)) {
#>                 crescs <- crescs * tmpsc$y.scale$"scaled:scale" + 
#>                   tmpsc$y.scale$"scaled:center"
#>                 ysvgr <- y[unlist(vgr)] * tmpsc$y.scale$"scaled:scale" + 
#>                   tmpsc$y.scale$"scaled:center"
#>             }
#>             else ysvgr <- y[unlist(vgr)]
#>             pinloss <- drop(pinloss(ysvgr, crescs, tau))
#>             ramloss <- drop(ramloss(ysvgr, crescs, tau))
#>             cross(ret) <- c(pinloss, ramloss)
#>         }
#>         return(ret)
#>     }
#>     .local(x, ...)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000027155f70>
#> <environment: namespace:kernlab>
#> 
#> Signatures:
#>         x       
#> target  "matrix"
#> defined "matrix"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I tried to edit the definition with `edit`:

```
kqr <- edit(getMethod('kqr',"matrix"))
```

However, then kqr will not work anymore:

```r
# create data
x <- as.matrix(sort(runif(300)))
y <- as.matrix(sin(pi*x) + rnorm(300,0,sd=exp(sin(2*pi*x))))

# calculate the median
kqr(x, y, tau = 0.5, C=0.15)
#> Error in param(ret) <- list(C = C, tau = tau) :could not find function "param<-"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The opposite of `getMethod` is fittingly called `setMethod`. But note that you’ll first need to unlock the namespace binding and modify the binding *in the package namespace of ’kqr‘*, otherwise your modified version won’t be found.

Comment: I suggest you use `trace`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. I struggled with unlocking the namespace binding and modifying the binding as suggested by Konrad Rudolph. However, `trace` works marvellous.

```r
#library
library(kernlab)

# create data
x <- as.matrix(sort(runif(300)))
y <- as.matrix(sin(pi*x) + rnorm(300,0,sd=exp(sin(2*pi*x))))

# trace with edit, add changes here (in my case I added the following on line 13: `print("everything OK, y is not NULL :D)`)
trace("kqr",signature="matrix",edit=TRUE)
#> [1] "kqr"

# calculate the median
kqr(x, y, tau = 0.5, C=0.15)
#> Tracing function ".local" in package "kernlab"
#> [1] "everything OK, y is not NULL :D"
#> Using automatic sigma estimation (sigest) for RBF or laplace kernel
#> Kernel Quantile Regression object of class "kqr" 
#> 
#> Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
#>  Hyperparameter : sigma =  14.8586545330765 
#> 
#> Regularization Cost Parameter C:  0.15
#> Number of training instances learned : 300 
#> Train error :  pinball loss :  0.331237291  rambloss : 0.5

# stop tracing
untrace("kqr",signature="matrix")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>